# console.log() is "Canceled" when looping unattended

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am able to reproduce a problem I am facing in a Node project in VS Code with the following:

```
for (let i=0; i<50; i++) {
  let text = [ Math.random()>0.5 ? "abc" : "ABC" ];
  console.log(i);
  console.log(text);
  console.log("*")
}
```

If I step through manually, everything works fine.

If I let the script run at full speed, at a random iteration, the words in red "Canceled" would be printed after the first `console.log` prints its output. From that point onward, the second `console.log(text)` is skipped or outputs a blank string (I am unable to tell which).

The other two `console.log()` statements continue to output the correct values till the end of the loop.

The color of the "Canceled" is the same as the output of my `console.error()`.

A sample run is as shown here where the anomaly happens after the seventh iteration:

[image]

I repeated the script many times, and each time the "Canceled" output happens at a different  iteration. If there is a breakpoint anywhere in the script, not necessarily in the loop, the "Canceled" does not happen.

Despite the erroneous output, the values of all variables seem to be correct. In my real code, I saved the final values of `text` to a file and they checked out correctly.

What is happening, and is there anything to worry about?

Comment: is there anything suspicious in the VSCode Developer Tools?

Comment: I can't reproduce the `Cancelled` output, I find it strange that `text` is displayed when stepping with the debugger, but nothing is logged when running without breakpoints, if you use `console.log(text[0]);` there is always an output

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, if I changed it to text[0] then there's no anomaly.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. I think it is some kind of VSCode bug.
When I print the `data` in a event callback, `console.log` behave as expected. But after a while, the main thread exists and `console.log` output `Canceled`.

```
import some modules...

vtgeojson(tiles, { tilesOnly: true })
  .on('data', function (data) {
    featurecollection.features.push(data);
    console.log(data)
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log(featurecollection);
    console.log(featurecollection.features.length);
  })
```

[image]

The problem disappears when I set the breakpoint and print the `data` line by line.

The problem also disappears when I run the script in the powershell.

[image]

Although the `console.log` is canceled, the `data` has been successfully pushed into the `feature list`. The behavior is most likely caused by the vscode terminal or the way that vscode handle the `console.log` command.

My node version is v12.20.0 and VSCode version is:

```
Version: 1.51.1 (system setup)
Commit: e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
Date: 2020-11-10T23:34:32.027Z
Electron: 9.3.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

I find someone else has a similar problem.
[Weird node.js console.log() output behaviour when printing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553205/weird-node-js-console-log-output-behaviour-when-printing-arrays)

Comment: the debug console has the possibility to show hierarchy in array variables logged, PS gets a full text dump of the variable, I think it follows a different path in the debug output

Answer (score 0):

the solution:
[answer by Than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667351/visual-studio-code-not-showing-console-logs)

without that settings, same problem.

```
{
  let values1 = [0, 1, 5, 10, 15];
  console.log(values1);
  console.log(values1);
  console.log(values1);
  console.log('====');
  values1.forEach((item, index, array) => {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(array);
    console.log('===');
  })
}
```

In vscode node.js environment, output is :

```
(5) [0, 1, 5, 10, 15]
====
0
0
===
1
1
===
5
2
===
10
3
===
15
4
===
```

while in browser the output is expected:

```
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]
==== 
0 
0 
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]
=== 
1 
1 
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]
=== 
5 
2 
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]

=== 
10
3
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]

===
15 
4 
Array(5) [ 0, 1, 5, 10, 15 ]

===
```

Comment: we are not interested what the browser shows, what does VSC show when you use the Than solution

Comment: @rioV8 I am providing more instances of this bug WITHOUT Than's solution, which fixed the bug. Actually, even [ "outputCapture": "avbsasdadfwaq"] can fixed the bug. I searched, this is obviously a bug, or a confusing feature, which I can't find any Microsoft's necessary official instructions.